# XSLT mapping Multiple source elements to a single target element

Tags: xslt, xsd

My requirement is I have a input xml which has the structure as below:

```
<Transaction-852>
<Loop-LIN>
        <Segment-LIN>
            <Element-350>001</Element-350>
            <Element-235>UP</Element-235>
            <Element-234>722868102237</Element-234>
            <Element-235_1>VP</Element-235_1>
            <Element-234_1>F2N036-06</Element-234_1>
        </Segment-LIN>
        <Loop-ZA>                                             
            <Segment-ZA>                                     
                <Element-859>QS</Element-859>
            </Segment-ZA>
            <Segment-SDQ>                                        
                <Element-355>EA</Element-355>                    
                <Element-66>92</Element-66>                      
                <Element-67>008</Element-67>                    
                <Element-380>1</Element-380>        
                <Element-67_1>018</Element-67_1>    
                <Element-380_1>1</Element-380_1>
                <Element-67_2>027</Element-67_2>
                <Element-380_2>1</Element-380_2>
                <Element-67_3>044</Element-67_3>
                <Element-380_3>-1</Element-380_3>
            </Segment-SDQ>
        </Loop-ZA>
    </Loop-LIN>
    <Loop-LIN>
        <Segment-LIN>
            <Element-350>002</Element-350>
            <Element-235>UP</Element-235>
            <Element-234>722868127469</Element-234>
            <Element-235_1>VP</Element-235_1>
            <Element-234_1>F2N025-10-GLD</Element-234_1>
        </Segment-LIN>
        <Loop-ZA>
            <Segment-ZA>
                <Element-859>QS</Element-859>
            </Segment-ZA>
            <Segment-SDQ>
                <Element-355>EA</Element-355>
                <Element-66>92</Element-66>
                <Element-67>007</Element-67>
                <Element-380>1</Element-380>
                <Element-67_1>010</Element-67_1>
                <Element-380_1>1</Element-380_1>
                <Element-67_2>017</Element-67_2>
                <Element-380_2>1</Element-380_2>
                <Element-67_3>020</Element-67_3>
                <Element-380_3>1</Element-380_3>
                <Element-67_4>021</Element-67_4>
                <Element-380_4>1</Element-380_4>
                <Element-67_5>022</Element-67_5>
                <Element-380_5>1</Element-380_5>
                <Element-67_6>025</Element-67_6>
                <Element-380_6>1</Element-380_6>
                <Element-67_7>028</Element-67_7>
                <Element-380_7>2</Element-380_7>
                <Element-67_8>048</Element-67_8>
                <Element-380_8>1</Element-380_8>
            </Segment-SDQ>
        </Loop-ZA>
    </Loop-LIN>
</Transaction-852>
```

The output XSD will be as:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Record-Record1">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="LIN-Element-350" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="LIN-Element-235" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="LIN-Element-234" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="LIN-Element-234_1" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="ZA-Element-859" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="SDQ-StoreNumber" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="SDQ-Qty" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

The elements in SDQ segment(((Element-67,Element-380) one set), ((Element-67_1,Element-380_1) one set), ((Element-67_2,Element-380_2)) one set) etc) in the Source should be matched to elements (SDQ-StoreNumber and SDQ-Qty) as a set in the target to display the below output.

And I need to write a file with the o/p as :

001 UP 722868102237 F2N036-06 QS 008 1
001 UP 722868102237 F2N036-06 QS 018 1
001 UP 722868102237 F2N036-06 QS 027 1
001 UP 722868102237 F2N036-06 QS 044 -1
002 UP 722868127469 F2N025-10-GLD QS 007 1
002 UP 722868127469 F2N025-10-GLD QS 010 1
002 UP 722868127469 F2N025-10-GLD QS 017 1
002 UP 722868127469 F2N025-10-GLD QS 020 1
002 UP 722868127469 F2N025-10-GLD QS 021 1
002 UP 722868127469 F2N025-10-GLD QS 022 1
002 UP 722868127469 F2N025-10-GLD QS 025 1
002 UP 722868127469 F2N025-10-GLD QS 028 1
002 UP 722868127469 F2N025-10-GLD QS 048 1

Output in the form of XSD:

```
<Transaction-852>
    <LIN>
        <LIN-Element-350>001</LIN-Element-350>
        <LIN-Element-235>UP</LIN-Element-235>
        <LIN-Element-234>722868102237</LIN-Element-234> 
        <LIN-Element-234_1>F2N036-06</LIN-Element-234_1>
        <ZA-Element-859>QS</ZA-Element-859>
        <SDQ-StoreNumber>008</SDQ-StoreNumber> 
        <SDQ-Qty>1</SDQ-Qty> 
    </LIN>
    <LIN>
        <LIN-Element-350>001</LIN-Element-350>
        <LIN-Element-235>UP</LIN-Element-235>
        <LIN-Element-234>722868102237</LIN-Element-234> 
        <LIN-Element-234_1>F2N036-06</LIN-Element-234_1>
        <ZA-Element-859>QS</ZA-Element-859>
        <SDQ-StoreNumber>018</SDQ-StoreNumber> 
        <SDQ-Qty>1</SDQ-Qty> 
    </LIN>
    <LIN>
        <LIN-Element-350>001</LIN-Element-350>
        <LIN-Element-235>UP</LIN-Element-235>
        <LIN-Element-234>722868102237</LIN-Element-234> 
        <LIN-Element-234_1>F2N036-06</LIN-Element-234_1>
        <ZA-Element-859>QS</ZA-Element-859>
        <SDQ-StoreNumber>027</SDQ-StoreNumber> 
        <SDQ-Qty>1</SDQ-Qty> 
    </LIN>
    <LIN>
        <LIN-Element-350>001</LIN-Element-350>
        <LIN-Element-235>UP</LIN-Element-235>
        <LIN-Element-234>722868102237</LIN-Element-234> 
        <LIN-Element-234_1>F2N036-06</LIN-Element-234_1>
        <ZA-Element-859>QS</ZA-Element-859>
        <SDQ-StoreNumber>44</SDQ-StoreNumber> 
        <SDQ-Qty>-1</SDQ-Qty> 
    </LIN>
    <LIN>
        <LIN-Element-350>002</LIN-Element-350>
        <LIN-Element-235>UP</LIN-Element-235>
        <LIN-Element-234>722868127469</LIN-Element-234> 
        <LIN-Element-234_1>F2N025-10-GLD</LIN-Element-234_1>
        <ZA-Element-859>QS</ZA-Element-859>
        <SDQ-StoreNumber>007</SDQ-StoreNumber> 
        <SDQ-Qty>1</SDQ-Qty> 
    </LIN>
    <LIN>
        <LIN-Element-350>002</LIN-Element-350>
        <LIN-Element-235>UP</LIN-Element-235>
        <LIN-Element-234>722868127469</LIN-Element-234> 
        <LIN-Element-234_1>F2N025-10-GLD</LIN-Element-234_1>
        <ZA-Element-859>QS</ZA-Element-859>
        <SDQ-StoreNumber>010</SDQ-StoreNumber> 
        <SDQ-Qty>1</SDQ-Qty> 
    </LIN>
    <LIN>
        <LIN-Element-350>002</LIN-Element-350>
        <LIN-Element-235>UP</LIN-Element-235>
        <LIN-Element-234>722868127469</LIN-Element-234> 
        <LIN-Element-234_1>F2N025-10-GLD</LIN-Element-234_1>
        <ZA-Element-859>QS</ZA-Element-859>
        <SDQ-StoreNumber>017</SDQ-StoreNumber> 
        <SDQ-Qty>1</SDQ-Qty> 
    </LIN>
    .
    .
    .
</Transaction-852>
```

Please help me with the code for achieving the desired functionality.

Thanks

Update 07-Mar-2016:

Latest source xml:

```
<Transaction-852>
    <Segment-ST>
            <Element-143>852</Element-143>
            <Element-329>0001</Element-329>
        </Segment-ST>
        <Segment-XQ>
            <Element-305>H</Element-305>
            <Element-373>20140105</Element-373>
            <Element-373_1>20140111</Element-373_1>
        </Segment-XQ>
        <Loop-LIN>
            <Segment-LIN>
                <Element-350>001</Element-350>
                <Element-235>UP</Element-235>
                <Element-234>722868102237</Element-234>
                <Element-235_1>VP</Element-235_1>
                <Element-234_1>F2N036-06</Element-234_1>
            </Segment-LIN>
            <Loop-ZA>
                <Segment-ZA>
                    <Element-859>QS</Element-859>
                </Segment-ZA>
                <Segment-SDQ>
                    <Element-355>EA</Element-355>
                    <Element-66>92</Element-66>
                    <Element-67>008</Element-67>
                    <Element-380>1</Element-380>
                    <Element-67_1>018</Element-67_1>
                    <Element-380_1>1</Element-380_1>
                    <Element-67_2>027</Element-67_2>
                    <Element-380_2>1</Element-380_2>
                    <Element-67_3>044</Element-67_3>
                    <Element-380_3>-1</Element-380_3>
                </Segment-SDQ>
            </Loop-ZA>
        </Loop-LIN>
      <Loop-LIN>
        <Segment-LIN>
            <Element-350>002</Element-350>
            <Element-235>UP</Element-235>
            <Element-234>722868127469</Element-234>
            <Element-235_1>VP</Element-235_1>
            <Element-234_1>F2N025-10-GLD</Element-234_1>
        </Segment-LIN>
        <Loop-ZA>
            <Segment-ZA>
                <Element-859>QS</Element-859>
            </Segment-ZA>
            <Segment-SDQ>
                <Element-355>EA</Element-355>
                <Element-66>92</Element-66>
                <Element-67>007</Element-67>
                <Element-380>1</Element-380>
                <Element-67_1>010</Element-67_1>
                <Element-380_1>1</Element-380_1>
                <Element-67_2>017</Element-67_2>
                <Element-380_2>1</Element-380_2>
                <Element-67_3>020</Element-67_3>
                <Element-380_3>1</Element-380_3>
                <Element-67_4>021</Element-67_4>
                <Element-380_4>1</Element-380_4>
                <Element-67_5>022</Element-67_5>
                <Element-380_5>1</Element-380_5>
                <Element-67_6>025</Element-67_6>
                <Element-380_6>1</Element-380_6>
                <Element-67_7>028</Element-67_7>
                <Element-380_7>2</Element-380_7>
                <Element-67_8>048</Element-67_8>
                <Element-380_8>1</Element-380_8>
            </Segment-SDQ>
        </Loop-ZA>
    </Loop-LIN>
    .
    .
    . 
   <Segment-SE>
        <Element-96>1545</Element-96>
        <Element-329>0001</Element-329>
   </Segment-SE>
  </Transaction-852>
```

Output as required:

```
    <Transaction-852>
    <LIN>
        <LIN-Element-350>001</LIN-Element-350>
        <LIN-Element-235>UP</LIN-Element-235>
        <LIN-Element-234>722868102237</LIN-Element-234> 
        <LIN-Element-234_1>F2N036-06</LIN-Element-234_1>
        <ZA-Element-859>QS</ZA-Element-859>
        <SDQ-StoreNumber>008</SDQ-StoreNumber> 
        <SDQ-Qty>1</SDQ-Qty> 
    </LIN>
    <LIN>
        <LIN-Element-350>001</LIN-Element-350>
        <LIN-Element-235>UP</LIN-Element-235>
        <LIN-Element-234>722868102237</LIN-Element-234> 
        <LIN-Element-234_1>F2N036-06</LIN-Element-234_1>
        <ZA-Element-859>QS</ZA-Element-859>
        <SDQ-StoreNumber>018</SDQ-StoreNumber> 
        <SDQ-Qty>1</SDQ-Qty> 
    </LIN>
    <LIN>
        <LIN-Element-350>001</LIN-Element-350>
        <LIN-Element-235>UP</LIN-Element-235>
        <LIN-Element-234>722868102237</LIN-Element-234> 
        <LIN-Element-234_1>F2N036-06</LIN-Element-234_1>
        <ZA-Element-859>QS</ZA-Element-859>
        <SDQ-StoreNumber>027</SDQ-StoreNumber> 
        <SDQ-Qty>1</SDQ-Qty> 
    </LIN>
    <LIN>
        <LIN-Element-350>001</LIN-Element-350>
        <LIN-Element-235>UP</LIN-Element-235>
        <LIN-Element-234>722868102237</LIN-Element-234> 
        <LIN-Element-234_1>F2N036-06</LIN-Element-234_1>
        <ZA-Element-859>QS</ZA-Element-859>
        <SDQ-StoreNumber>44</SDQ-StoreNumber> 
        <SDQ-Qty>-1</SDQ-Qty> 
    </LIN>
    <LIN>
        <LIN-Element-350>002</LIN-Element-350>
        <LIN-Element-235>UP</LIN-Element-235>
        <LIN-Element-234>722868127469</LIN-Element-234> 
        <LIN-Element-234_1>F2N025-10-GLD</LIN-Element-234_1>
        <ZA-Element-859>QS</ZA-Element-859>
        <SDQ-StoreNumber>007</SDQ-StoreNumber> 
        <SDQ-Qty>1</SDQ-Qty> 
    </LIN>
    <LIN>
        <LIN-Element-350>002</LIN-Element-350>
        <LIN-Element-235>UP</LIN-Element-235>
        <LIN-Element-234>722868127469</LIN-Element-234> 
        <LIN-Element-234_1>F2N025-10-GLD</LIN-Element-234_1>
        <ZA-Element-859>QS</ZA-Element-859>
        <SDQ-StoreNumber>010</SDQ-StoreNumber> 
        <SDQ-Qty>1</SDQ-Qty> 
    </LIN>
    <LIN>
        <LIN-Element-350>002</LIN-Element-350>
        <LIN-Element-235>UP</LIN-Element-235>
        <LIN-Element-234>722868127469</LIN-Element-234> 
        <LIN-Element-234_1>F2N025-10-GLD</LIN-Element-234_1>
        <ZA-Element-859>QS</ZA-Element-859>
        <SDQ-StoreNumber>017</SDQ-StoreNumber> 
        <SDQ-Qty>1</SDQ-Qty> 
    </LIN>
    .
    .
    .
</Transaction-852>
```

With the present code its considering the `<Segment-ST>` and `<Segment-XQ>` also and the output Im getting is like:

## 852 0001 H 20140105 20140111 001 UP 722868102237 VP F2N036-06 QS EA 92 008 1 018 1 027 1 044 -1 002 UP 722868127469 VP F2N025-10-GLD QS EA 92 007 1 010 1 017 1 020 1 021 1 022 1 025 1 028 2 048 1

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want the output as text or as XML?

Comment: Hi Michael.. I need the output as xml and using Oracle SOA it will be converted to text.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following approach which simply transforms all elements starting with `Element-67` and then creates the corresponding elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Transaction-852">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//Segment-SDQ/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'Element-67')]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Segment-SDQ/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'Element-67')]">
        <LIN>
            <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::Loop-LIN/Segment-LIN/* | ancestor::Loop-ZA/Segment-ZA/Element-859"/>
            <SDQ-StoreNumber>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </SDQ-StoreNumber>
            <SDQ-Qty>
                <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[starts-with(local-name(), 'Element-38')][1]"/>
            </SDQ-Qty>
        </LIN>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result I get is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Transaction-852>
   <LIN>
      <Element-350>001</Element-350>
      <Element-235>UP</Element-235>
      <Element-234>722868102237</Element-234>
      <Element-235_1>VP</Element-235_1>
      <Element-234_1>F2N036-06</Element-234_1>
      <Element-859>QS</Element-859>
      <SDQ-StoreNumber>008</SDQ-StoreNumber>
      <SDQ-Qty>1</SDQ-Qty>
   </LIN>
   <LIN>
      <Element-350>001</Element-350>
      <Element-235>UP</Element-235>
      <Element-234>722868102237</Element-234>
      <Element-235_1>VP</Element-235_1>
      <Element-234_1>F2N036-06</Element-234_1>
      <Element-859>QS</Element-859>
      <SDQ-StoreNumber>018</SDQ-StoreNumber>
      <SDQ-Qty>1</SDQ-Qty>
   </LIN>
   <LIN>
      <Element-350>001</Element-350>
      <Element-235>UP</Element-235>
      <Element-234>722868102237</Element-234>
      <Element-235_1>VP</Element-235_1>
      <Element-234_1>F2N036-06</Element-234_1>
      <Element-859>QS</Element-859>
      <SDQ-StoreNumber>027</SDQ-StoreNumber>
      <SDQ-Qty>1</SDQ-Qty>
   </LIN>
   <LIN>
      <Element-350>001</Element-350>
      <Element-235>UP</Element-235>
      <Element-234>722868102237</Element-234>
      <Element-235_1>VP</Element-235_1>
      <Element-234_1>F2N036-06</Element-234_1>
      <Element-859>QS</Element-859>
      <SDQ-StoreNumber>044</SDQ-StoreNumber>
      <SDQ-Qty>-1</SDQ-Qty>
   </LIN>
   <LIN>
      <Element-350>002</Element-350>
      <Element-235>UP</Element-235>
      <Element-234>722868127469</Element-234>
      <Element-235_1>VP</Element-235_1>
      <Element-234_1>F2N025-10-GLD</Element-234_1>
      <Element-859>QS</Element-859>
      <SDQ-StoreNumber>007</SDQ-StoreNumber>
      <SDQ-Qty>1</SDQ-Qty>
   </LIN>
   <LIN>
      <Element-350>002</Element-350>
      <Element-235>UP</Element-235>
      <Element-234>722868127469</Element-234>
      <Element-235_1>VP</Element-235_1>
      <Element-234_1>F2N025-10-GLD</Element-234_1>
      <Element-859>QS</Element-859>
      <SDQ-StoreNumber>010</SDQ-StoreNumber>
      <SDQ-Qty>1</SDQ-Qty>
   </LIN>
   <LIN>
      <Element-350>002</Element-350>
      <Element-235>UP</Element-235>
      <Element-234>722868127469</Element-234>
      <Element-235_1>VP</Element-235_1>
      <Element-234_1>F2N025-10-GLD</Element-234_1>
      <Element-859>QS</Element-859>
      <SDQ-StoreNumber>017</SDQ-StoreNumber>
      <SDQ-Qty>1</SDQ-Qty>
   </LIN>
   <LIN>
      <Element-350>002</Element-350>
      <Element-235>UP</Element-235>
      <Element-234>722868127469</Element-234>
      <Element-235_1>VP</Element-235_1>
      <Element-234_1>F2N025-10-GLD</Element-234_1>
      <Element-859>QS</Element-859>
      <SDQ-StoreNumber>020</SDQ-StoreNumber>
      <SDQ-Qty>1</SDQ-Qty>
   </LIN>
   <LIN>
      <Element-350>002</Element-350>
      <Element-235>UP</Element-235>
      <Element-234>722868127469</Element-234>
      <Element-235_1>VP</Element-235_1>
      <Element-234_1>F2N025-10-GLD</Element-234_1>
      <Element-859>QS</Element-859>
      <SDQ-StoreNumber>021</SDQ-StoreNumber>
      <SDQ-Qty>1</SDQ-Qty>
   </LIN>
   <LIN>
      <Element-350>002</Element-350>
      <Element-235>UP</Element-235>
      <Element-234>722868127469</Element-234>
      <Element-235_1>VP</Element-235_1>
      <Element-234_1>F2N025-10-GLD</Element-234_1>
      <Element-859>QS</Element-859>
      <SDQ-StoreNumber>022</SDQ-StoreNumber>
      <SDQ-Qty>1</SDQ-Qty>
   </LIN>
   <LIN>
      <Element-350>002</Element-350>
      <Element-235>UP</Element-235>
      <Element-234>722868127469</Element-234>
      <Element-235_1>VP</Element-235_1>
      <Element-234_1>F2N025-10-GLD</Element-234_1>
      <Element-859>QS</Element-859>
      <SDQ-StoreNumber>025</SDQ-StoreNumber>
      <SDQ-Qty>1</SDQ-Qty>
   </LIN>
   <LIN>
      <Element-350>002</Element-350>
      <Element-235>UP</Element-235>
      <Element-234>722868127469</Element-234>
      <Element-235_1>VP</Element-235_1>
      <Element-234_1>F2N025-10-GLD</Element-234_1>
      <Element-859>QS</Element-859>
      <SDQ-StoreNumber>028</SDQ-StoreNumber>
      <SDQ-Qty>2</SDQ-Qty>
   </LIN>
   <LIN>
      <Element-350>002</Element-350>
      <Element-235>UP</Element-235>
      <Element-234>722868127469</Element-234>
      <Element-235_1>VP</Element-235_1>
      <Element-234_1>F2N025-10-GLD</Element-234_1>
      <Element-859>QS</Element-859>
      <SDQ-StoreNumber>048</SDQ-StoreNumber>
      <SDQ-Qty>1</SDQ-Qty>
   </LIN>
</Transaction-852>
```

As for your comment about unwanted lines, the only difference I see in your latest output sample is the removal of `Element-235_1` elements, if you don't want them you can change the code to do that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Transaction-852">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//Segment-SDQ/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'Element-67')]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Segment-SDQ/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'Element-67')]">
        <LIN>
            <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::Loop-LIN/Segment-LIN/*[not(self::Element-235_1)] | ancestor::Loop-ZA/Segment-ZA/Element-859"/>
            <SDQ-StoreNumber>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </SDQ-StoreNumber>
            <SDQ-Qty>
                <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[starts-with(local-name(), 'Element-38')][1]"/>
            </SDQ-Qty>
        </LIN>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Martin.. Thanks alot for your help. The code is working as required. Now my input XSD has some more elements before <LIN> and due to this the code is considering all the elements and writing unwanted lines also. The latest requirement is updated at the last of the Question. Please have a look and let me know how can it be achieved. Thanks In Advance

Comment: @Shankar, I have edited the answer and shown how to exclude certain elements. But I don't see why the `Segment-ST` would be copied, if you still have problems then consider to ask a new question.

Comment: Hi Martin.. I added a new question with complete description of the requirement. can you go through the link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35844921/xslt-transformation-multiple-elements-in-the-source-to-single-element-in-target?noredirect=1#comment59355446_35844921" and help me getting the solution.. Thanks