# XSLT Transformation: Multiple elements in the source to single element in Target XSD

Tags: xslt

Please bear with my lengthy request, Im very new to XSLT's so facing these issues..
Below is the input source XML, I need to Transform it to write the data as per the Output XSD. Please help me in this context.

================

## Start Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Receive_Read852File_Read_IV>
   <part xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="body">
      <Transaction-852 xmlns="http://www.edifecs.com/xdata/200" XDataVersion="2.0" Standard="X12" Version="V4010" CreatedDate="2016-03-03T13:49:27" CreatedBy="XEngine_3016" GUID="{BF24BE6C-E146-11E5-8E7D-005056A223A6}">
    <Internal-Properties>
        <Data-Structure Name="Interchange">
            <Lookup Name="InterchangeControlVersion">00400</Lookup>
            <Property Name="ElementDelimiter">0x2a</Property>
            <Data-Structure Name="Group">
                <Lookup Name="GroupSenderID">000099999</Lookup>
                <Lookup Name="GroupVersionNumber">004010</Lookup>
                <Property Name="GroupAgencyCode">X</Property>
                <Property Name="GroupControlNumber">43350</Property>
                <Data-Structure Name="Transaction">
                    <Lookup Name="TransactionID">852</Lookup>
                    <Property Name="TransactionTrailerControlNumber">0001</Property>
                </Data-Structure>
            </Data-Structure>
        </Data-Structure>
    </Internal-Properties>
    <Segment-ST>
        <Element-143>852</Element-143>
        <Element-329>0001</Element-329>
    </Segment-ST>
    <Segment-XQ>
        <Element-305>H</Element-305>
        <Element-373>20140105</Element-373>
        <Element-373_1>20140111</Element-373_1>
    </Segment-XQ>
    <Loop-LIN>
        <Segment-LIN>
            <Element-350>001</Element-350>
            <Element-235>UP</Element-235>
            <Element-234>722868102237</Element-234>
            <Element-235_1>VP</Element-235_1>
            <Element-234_1>F2N036-06</Element-234_1>
        </Segment-LIN>
        <Loop-ZA>
            <Segment-ZA>
                <Element-859>QS</Element-859>
            </Segment-ZA>
            <Segment-SDQ>
                <Element-355>EA</Element-355>
                <Element-66>92</Element-66>
                <Element-67>008</Element-67>
                <Element-380>1</Element-380>
                <Element-67_1>018</Element-67_1>
                <Element-380_1>1</Element-380_1>
                <Element-67_2>027</Element-67_2>
                <Element-380_2>1</Element-380_2>
            </Segment-SDQ>
        </Loop-ZA>
    </Loop-LIN>
    <Loop-LIN>
        <Segment-LIN>
            <Element-350>002</Element-350>
            <Element-235>UP</Element-235>
            <Element-234>722868127469</Element-234>
            <Element-235_1>VP</Element-235_1>
            <Element-234_1>F2N025-10-GLD</Element-234_1>
        </Segment-LIN>
        <Loop-ZA>
            <Segment-ZA>
                <Element-859>QS</Element-859>
            </Segment-ZA>
            <Segment-SDQ>
                <Element-355>EA</Element-355>
                <Element-66>92</Element-66>
                <Element-67>007</Element-67>
                <Element-380>1</Element-380>
                <Element-67_1>010</Element-67_1>
                <Element-380_1>1</Element-380_1>
                <Element-67_2>017</Element-67_2>
                <Element-380_2>1</Element-380_2>
                <Element-67_3>020</Element-67_3>
                <Element-380_3>1</Element-380_3>
                <Element-67_4>021</Element-67_4>
                <Element-380_4>1</Element-380_4>
                <Element-67_5>022</Element-67_5>
                <Element-380_5>1</Element-380_5>
                <Element-67_6>025</Element-67_6>
                <Element-380_6>1</Element-380_6>
                <Element-67_7>028</Element-67_7>
                <Element-380_7>2</Element-380_7>
                <Element-67_8>048</Element-67_8>
                <Element-380_8>1</Element-380_8>
            </Segment-SDQ>
        </Loop-ZA>
    </Loop-LIN>
    <Segment-SE>
        <Element-96>1545</Element-96>
        <Element-329>0001</Element-329>
    </Segment-SE>
</Transaction-852>
   </part>
```

## End Input XML

=================

## Start Output XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Automatically generated by EDIFECS SpecBuilder (http://www.edifecs.com) -->
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.edifecs.com/xdata/200" targetNamespace="http://www.edifecs.com/xdata/200" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:element name="Transaction-852">
        <xsd:complexType name="Record-Record1">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Field-TP_CODE" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Field-DATE" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Field-Customer_Part_Number" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Field-UPC" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Field-BELKIN_PART" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Field-CTP_UNIT_PRICE" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Field-ACTIVITY" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Field-StoreNumber" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Field-QTY" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    </Transaction-852>
</xsd:schema>
```

=================

## END Output XSD

Now the mapping conditions are:

1. Source> "Transaction-852> Segment-XQ> Element-373" should be mapped to "Transaction-852> Record-Record1 > Field-DATE" target side
2. Source> "Transaction-852> Loop-LIN > Segment-LIN > Element-350" should be mapped to "Transaction-852> Record-Record1 > Field-UPC" target side
3. Source> "Transaction-852> Loop-LIN > Segment-LIN > Element-234" should be mapped to "Transaction-852> Record-Record1 > Field-BELKIN_PART" target side
4. Source> "Transaction-852> Loop-LIN > Loop-ZA> Segment-ZA > Element-859" should be mapped to "Transaction-852> Record-Record1 > Field-ACTIVITY" target side
5. Source> "Transaction-852> Loop-LIN > Loop-ZA> Segment-SDQ > Element-67" should be mapped to "Transaction-852> Record-Record1 > Field-StoreNumber" target side
6. Source> "Transaction-852> Loop-LIN > Loop-ZA> Segment-SDQ > Element-380" should be mapped to "Transaction-852> Record-Record1 > Field-QTY" target side

Now the mapping conditions 5 and 6 will repeat for all the elements starting "Element-67" to Element-67_9 and Element-380 to Element-380_9 depending upon the availability of the elements.

I tried using For-each condition for mappings 1 to 3, but facing issue while trying to map 4 and 5.
Please help me in resolving this.

Required Output XML Format:

```
<Transaction-852> 
<Record-Record1> 
<Field-TP_CODE>THD</Field-TP_CODE>
<Field-UPC>001</Field-UPC>
<Field-DATE>20140105</Field-DATE>
<Field-BELKIN_PART>722868102237</Field-BELKIN_PART>
<Field-ACTIVITY>QS</Field-ACTIVITY>
<Field-StoreNumber>008</Field-StoreNumber>
<Field-QTY>1</Field-QTY>
</Record-Record1>
<Record-Record1> 
<Field-TP_CODE>THD</Field-TP_CODE>
<Field-UPC>001</Field-UPC>
<Field-DATE>20140105</Field-DATE>
<Field-BELKIN_PART>722868102237</Field-BELKIN_PART>
<Field-ACTIVITY>QS</Field-ACTIVITY>
<Field-StoreNumber>018</Field-StoreNumber>
<Field-QTY>1</Field-QTY>
</Record-Record1>
<Record-Record1> 
<Field-TP_CODE>THD</Field-TP_CODE>
<Field-UPC>001</Field-UPC>
<Field-DATE>20140105</Field-DATE>
<Field-BELKIN_PART>722868102237</Field-BELKIN_PART>
<Field-ACTIVITY>QS</Field-ACTIVITY>
<Field-StoreNumber>027</Field-StoreNumber>
<Field-QTY>1</Field-QTY>
</Record-Record1>
<Record-Record1> 
<Field-TP_CODE>THD</Field-TP_CODE>
<Field-UPC>002</Field-UPC>
<Field-DATE>20140105</Field-DATE>
<Field-BELKIN_PART>722868127469</Field-BELKIN_PART>
<Field-ACTIVITY>QS</Field-ACTIVITY>
<Field-StoreNumber>007</Field-StoreNumber>
<Field-QTY>1</Field-QTY>
</Record-Record1>
<Record-Record1> 
<Field-TP_CODE>THD</Field-TP_CODE>
<Field-UPC>002</Field-UPC>
<Field-DATE>20140105</Field-DATE>
<Field-BELKIN_PART>722868127469</Field-BELKIN_PART>
<Field-ACTIVITY>QS</Field-ACTIVITY>
<Field-StoreNumber>010</Field-StoreNumber>
<Field-QTY>1</Field-QTY>
</Record-Record1>
.
.
.
</Transaction-852>
```

I tried using For-each condition for mappings 1 to 3, but facing issue while trying to map 4 and 5, only the first record(Element-67) is getting mapped and for the rest its throwing error.
Please help me in resolving this.

Comment: Please minimize your question to one, specific problem - see: [mcve]

Comment: You can take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) as well to understand how SO works.